# How to add action for submit button

Tags: php, database, form-submit, submit-button

sry for my amateur question. I wrote this code for get text from input and add in to database:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="fa">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>My Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action=""  method="POST">
            <label for="name" id="app_name_label"  >name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name_textfield">

            <input type="submit" name"Submit" value="send" >
        </form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
        include_once("config.php");
    $con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass)
    or die(mysql_error());

    $selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) 
    or die(mysql_error());

    if($selected){
    $name = $_REQUEST['name'];

    $ins = "INSERT INTO infos (app_name )  VALUES ('$name')";
    $saved=mysql_query($ins );
    if($saved)
    {
        echo "Saved!!";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Don't Saved!!";
    }

    }
    mysql_close($con);
}


?>

    </body>
</html>
```

My database doesn't have any problem
But when i run it, nothing write to my database! :( what should i do?
I think problem is in `isset($_POST['Submit'])`.

Comment: The code should be in two different scripts, first the html part is requested and displayed by the browser. Then the script noted down in the forms `action` attribute is called and the forms content sent there. That file (a php file) processes the form data.

Comment: The code does not have to be in two separate files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything else is ok, then I am afraid you have a simple typo in your code that is causing you the problem.

```
 <input type="submit" name"Submit" value="send" >
```

should be

```
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="send" >
```

You have missed the equal to sign in your code after name. :)

On a side note, you should not use `$_REQUEST['name']` but instead use `$_POST['name']` when the form method is post. It is more secure. And secondly, try to use [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) database extension instead of using mysql. mysql extension is deprecated from PHP 5.5 onward.

Comment: the problem was just equal :(

Comment: @Ahmad yeah, sometimes this silly problems happen :)

Answer (score 1):

For your information, better use php tags above the body and display errors with sessions, plus why would you include_once("config.php") after submition is executed but not when actual file is loaded? Here is script which does the same what you trying to achieve but handling is much better.

```
<?php
include_once("config.php");

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])){

     $err = array();

     $name = $_POST['name'];

     if(!$name){
          $err[] = 'All fields required';
     } 

if(!count($err)){

    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($name); //Make sure you escape unwanted chars

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("INSERT INTO infos (app_name )  VALUES ('$name')"));

    if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1)  
    {
        $_SESSION['msg']['succ'] = 'Sent!';
        header("Location: index.php");
    } else{
        $_SESSION['msg']['err'] = 'Noooooo!';
    }   
}

?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="fa">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>My Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action=""  method="POST">
            <?php   
            // Lets output message
    if($_SESSION['msg']['err'])
    {
        echo $_SESSION['msg']['err'];
        unset($_SESSION['msg']['err']);
    }
    if($_SESSION['msg']['succ'])
    {
        echo $_SESSION['msg']['succ'];
        unset($_SESSION['msg']['succ']);
    }
        ?>  

            <label id="app_name_label">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name_textfield">

            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="send">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```